# jquery live typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, typing

To understand exactly what I'm talking about check out this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/9mNc4/1/)

So, I want to get rid of the input box, I mean to type something on a div with a red background for example and when I type google and press enter I want to send me to the google website  and when I type yahoo to send me on the yahoo website.
How I can achieve this? I'm not very good at javascript. 
Thanks!

Comment: please select correct answer so people can know what is solution.

Answer (score 2):

this may help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div[contenteditable]').focus();
    $('div[contenteditable]').keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.which == 13) 
    {
       switch ($(this).html()) {
        case 'google':
            document.location = 'http://google.com'
            break;    
        case 'yahoo':
            document.location = 'http://yahoo.com'
            break;
          } 
    } 
    });

});
</script>
<style>
div[contenteditable] { background:red; width:200px;height:20px; padding:5px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div contenteditable></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! but how can this script works only with 2 words for example google or yahoo ?

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working... nothing happens if I type yahoo and hit "enter"

Comment: I test this in Firefox, chrome and IE, which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div to your page that has the CONTENTEDITABLE="true" attribute on it. Than add a button or whatsoever that indicated that the user is done (can also be an hit on the return key). At that point, check the value in the div, show an error message if needed or redirect the page if the entered value is valid (e.g. document.location.href = 'http://www.' + userValue + '.com';)

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide your input by css so it looks like you're writing in a div but really its just an approprietly styled input.

[Your version with a little change](http://jsfiddle.net/9mNc4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/9mNc4/3/

Comment: [One that works](http://jsfiddle.net/9mNc4/5/). You really need to explain what you're doing here.